# Angular CLI run both test report and code coverage report

Tags: angular, karma-runner

**Is it possible, in Angular CLI, to start testing with Karma and return code coverage by the same time?**

#### Explanation

Running `ng test` starts Chrome and run the tests, so I can see the results on Chrome.

Running `ng test -cc` starts Chrome, run the tests **without** displaying tests results and produces code coverage report in `coverage` directory.

Is it possible to have both? So I could benefit of "live" test-coding experience AND having code report generated along with tests results displayed in Chrome.

#### Current `karma.conf.js`

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli', 'intl-shim'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-intl-shim')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false },
      { pattern: './node_modules/intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-US.js', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to use the html reporter as well when running with coverage:

```
 reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
          ? ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage-istanbul']
          : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
```

You can basically use different reporters based on the `-cc` flag.

Note that the 'progress' reporter is the console-based running report.

Comment: Thanks I lack config skills! I didn't think I could chain up reporters that way. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Reporters are pretty cool, you can even write your own to stick your nose into running tests and do whatever. The angular-cli config on the other hand is quite confusing and documentation is a bit lacking unfortunately.

Comment: Ok I will dive into this! Quite a challenge.